# ctypes Segmentation Fault when binding rsvg

Tags: python, ctypes, ubuntu-18.04, pycairo, librsvg

I have a simple python ctypes wrapper around rsvg to be used with cairo. It seems to work on `ubuntu 16` but when I try it on `ubuntu 18` I get a Segmentation error. I have looked at the cairo docs for an example of how this can be done, so nothing fancy.(https://www.cairographics.org/cookbook/librsvgpython/).

```
from ctypes import CDLL, Structure, byref, c_byte, c_double, c_int, c_void_p
# CDLL: Instances of this class represent loaded shared libraries.
l = CDLL('librsvg-2.so.2')
class rsvgHandle():
    class RsvgDimensionData(Structure):
        _fields_ = [("width", c_int),
                    ("height", c_int),
                    ("em", c_double),
                    ("ex", c_double)]
    class PycairoContext(Structure):
        _fields_ = [("PyObject_HEAD", c_byte * object.__basicsize__),
                    ("ctx", c_void_p),
                    ("base", c_void_p)]
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        error = ''
        self.handle = l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file(self.path, error)

    def get_dimension_data(self):
        svgDim = self.RsvgDimensionData()
        l.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions(self.handle, byref(svgDim))
        return (svgDim.width, svgDim.height)

    def render_cairo(self, ctx):
        ctx.save()
        z = self.PycairoContext.from_address(id(ctx))
        l.rsvg_handle_render_cairo(self.handle, z.ctx)
        ctx.restore()
class rsvgClass():
    def Handle(self, file):
        return rsvgHandle(file)

rsvg = rsvgClass()
svg_handle = rsvg.Handle(fpath)
svg_width, svg_height = svg_handle.get_dimension_data()[:2]
svg_handle.render_cairo(context)
```

The error occurs inside `get_dimension_data` at the line `l.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions(self.handle, byref(svgDim))`

The trace isn't too helpful it says Segmenation Fault and a bunch of these

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2(rsvg_handle_get_dimensions+0)
>   [0x7ff70b01ed50]
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c)
>   [0x7ff71f52adae]
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call+0x22f) [0x7ff71f52a71f]
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_ctypes_callproc+0x2a4)
>   [0x7ff71f73dcc4]
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x106c5)
>   [0x7ff71f73d6c5]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5bf6) [0x7ff7247eb366]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x8b5b) [0x7ff7247ee2cb]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7d8) [0x7ff72492a908]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5bf6) [0x7ff7247eb366]

Does anyone know what could be going on in my `ubuntu 18` environment to cause this issue ? Or alternatively how I could render an svg into an open cairo context (as shown in the last line of the code) on ubuntu 18 ? (the readymade python binding for rsvg is removed from ubuntu 18 btw which is why im trying ctypes to begin with)

Comment: Most likely the type of one or more of your struct fields went from int to long.

Comment: Do you mean that for some reason on ubuntu 18 a `long` would be required for `rsvg` instead of an `int` ?

Comment: Possible dupe of [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011).